# I want to cancel an event handler on my row when a button within the row is clicked

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, datatables

I am using datatables and have an event handler set so that when a row is clicked, it opens another page. However, each row contains a button which will open a modal dialog.  I'm trying to set a click handler on the button so that when it's pressed, the new page event is cancelled and the modal opens instead.  Here is my code:

```
$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
    window.location.href = root+'/path';
});

$('#ModalBtn').click(function() {
    $("#table_id tbody").unbind();
});
```

UPDATE:
Here is the rest of the script. I think maybe the cause of the trouble is the datatables var.  If I remove that, the event handlers work correctly, like in Amin's demo:

```
var searchTable = $('#table_id').dataTable({
    "ajax": "array.php",
    "aoColumns": [ 
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                return '<button id="ModalBtn" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>';
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: To prevent default behaviour and bubbling up add `return false` at the end of event handler's function.

Comment: What about your HTML code and full example in fiddle?

Comment: @Regent:  Took awhile to remove irrelevant code.  Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/bLwr37zb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand, but are you not overcomplicating things here? As I understand, you just want a click event on the row / `<tr>`, and wants to open a popup (perhaps bootstrap?) when clicking on the button. But not both at the same time. Simply :

```js
$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'ModalBtn') {
        return;
    }
    alert('<tr> clicked');
});
```

And skip all the rest. Here is a complete example doing exactly what you want, with a `<tr>` click event and a bootstrap modal, actually showing up when you are clickng on the `add`-button -> **http://jsfiddle.net/45tf0095/**

As @Regent mentions, duplicated `id`'s is very bad practice. But this is not why you are having the problem described in the question, it is a different matter. Test for a match on `e.target.className`, and skip the button `id`'s instead, if you want to update your code to everyday standards.

Comment: Works great!  Thank you for taking the time to weigh in - much appreciated.  Is it ok to ask a follow-up question or should I close this out first and reference it in a new question?

Comment: How do I format "e.target.className"?  I tried adding "ModalBtn" back to the class and removing the id, then changed the flag to this:
    if (e.target.className === 'ModalBtn') {
but it's ignored.

Comment: @SquatChimo as `(e.target.className === 'btn')` see **http://jsfiddle.net/ezdrpx9v/**

Comment: Many ways, but in your case like this (untested) `e.target.className.split(' ').indexOf('btn')) {` etc hope you get the idea.

Comment: @SquatChimo And as alternative version to mentioned `if (e.target.className.split(/\s+/).indexOf('btn') >= 0)` you can use `if ($(e.target).hasClass('btn'))`

Comment: @davidkonrad I actually used this idea ( `if (e.target...` ) in one of my answers - don't know why I didn't come to it in this question, +1 :)

Comment: @Regent super you are following up. I really like that.

Answer (score 2):

And here is reason: elements IDs **must** be unique. `$('#ModalBtn').click(function() {` binds event handler only to first "Add" button.

Change

```
return '<button id="ModalBtn" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>';
```

to

```
return '<button class="ModalBtn btn btn-inverse btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>';
```

And code will look like:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLwr37zb/2/).

```
var buttonClicked = false;

$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function()
{
    if (!buttonClicked)
    {
        alert('tr clicked!');
    }
    else
    {
        buttonClicked = false; //it is important, do not omit this line
    }
});

$('.ModalBtn').click(function()
{
    alert('Button is clicked');
    buttonClicked = true;
});
```

Update. For dynamically created buttons delegated event handler can be used:

```
$('#table_id tbody').on('click', '.ModalBtn', function()
{
    alert('Button is clicked');
    buttonClicked = true;
});
```

Comment: thanks, this works great.  However, I'm still having my original issue where a button displayed on the datatables row is firing secondary and the row click handler is still firing first.  If I make my datatable array static and defined in the JS, it works great.  If I pull my data array from another page through ajax, I have this issue.  I'm getting closer...not there yet.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show you what I mean.  If I comment out the dynamic "ajax" load and use the static "data", everything works great.  If I use the dynamic dataset and comment out the static, the <tr> fires first, then the button fires.  Something about the dynamic load is ignoring the button handler until after the row handler fires (flag doesn't deter it).  Any ideas?

Comment: @SquatChimo well, try `$('#table_id tbody').on('click', '.ModalBtn', function()` instead of `$('.ModalBtn').click(function()`

Comment: You can easily have many elements with the same ID. It is not OP's problem. Think about it. The browser itself deal with this during to the fact, that many pages expose duplicated ID's. It is very bad to do, but it is not the cause of OP problem.

Comment: +1, You are right, but this is **not the reason** for the failure in OP.All modern browsers "supports" duplicated id's. It is "illegal", and not very vice, in fact "stupid", but it works if you really want. Like malformed markup and so on.

Comment: @davidkonrad The whole phrase is something like "elements IDs must be unique for adequate selector handling". `$('#ModalBtn').click` works only for the first button. Yes, `$('#table_id tbody').on('click', '#ModalBtn', function() {` is alternative (to switching to classes) workable solution, but I still suppose that I'm not here only for fixing errors in people's code, but also for pointing out "bad places" in their code.